Trouble with Auto-Mounting External HDD on Ubuntu Server
I’m having a issue with automatically mounting an external HDD on my Ubuntu server that runs Jellyfin.
System Information:
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
External HDD Format: exFAT
The external HDD is connected via a USB switch, and I want it to auto-mount when I reconnect it after unplugging.
I have created a UDEV rule to handle the automatic mounting, but it only seems to work on rebooting the server, not when I simply disconnect and reconnect the HDD.
UDEV rule:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sdb2", ATTRS{serial}=="00000000NT17B957", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/mount-external-hdd.sh"

mount-external-hdd.sh script:
#!/bin/bash
mount /mnt/external-hdd


there are two videos from LearnLinuxTV which I have found helpful (but not specific to Jellyfin about which I know nothing) The first is Format and Mounting Storage Volumes Disks and the second is Configuring the fstab file. I hope you find them as useful as I have in practice.
